# How to make jersey 1.9 and jersey 2 coexist?

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I have one application which require both jersey 1.9 and jersey 2. And I don't want to build it to assembly jar, so shade doesn't work for me. Is there any other way to make them coexist ? Thanks

Comment: Why does your application require both versions of Jersey? This seems like a really terrible idea – especially if you're not going to shade, it's just asking for enormous headaches.

Comment: I agree 100% with @MattBall's comment.

Comment: Maven will only resolve one dependency in your module and will omit the other versions to avoid any conflict. Even if multiple versions of the same dependency are used in the whole dependency hierarchy, Maven will pick one version using the "nearest in the dependency tree" strategy.

Comment: Are you using osgi ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Maven Shade plugin to relocate the Jersey 1 and JAX-RS API 1.0 package names, and then use the resulting jar with Jersey 2 jars.  Unfortunately, there's no other way I know of to have them coexist.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#relocations

Comment: Why the down vote?  I've personally done this before, so I know that it works.  :-)

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I think it's because he wrote: `I don't want to build it to assembly jar, so shade doesn't work for me`.

Comment: Thanks @MaxG.  It would help if I read the question more carefully!